# Multiple dashboard in angular 4 based on login

Tags: angular, typescript

How can i use particular dashboard while login as specific user in Angular 4.
For example : If i logged in as USER1 , dashboard 1 should visisble and rest of the dashboard should get Hide. Please help me in this...

Comment: Please post your code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

After login the page will be redirect to dashboard page. This is default page. So when you logged in as multiple user , you need to give router in dashboard.component.ts, it will take you to particular dashboard. To do this u need to get data from API